# Unable to set the segue identifier in XCode 4.6 because Attributes Inspector is blank

Tags: ios, segue, xcode4.6

I have an iPad app (XCode 4.6, iOS 6.2, ARC and Storyboards).  Everything is connected properly using segues; however, when I click on a segue, I am presented with a blank Attributes inspector.  Why and how do I fix it?

Here is the structure of the app:

[image]

And here is what I see when I click on any segue:

[image]

Comment: Try clicking again on the segue.

Comment: It minimizes the diagram; clicking again brings it to full size...

Comment: Double click the canvas, or click the equal sign(=) at the bottom right of the canvas, to bring it 100% zoom. Then select the segue icon.

Comment: Nope... same thing... (See Steve Wilford's answer below)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't set an identifier of a segue that's created between a `UINavigationController` or a `UITabBarController`. This is expected behaviour.

Segues between other view controllers should work OK though. Try selecting a different file and then return to the storyboard or try restarting Xcode (fixes a lot of annoying problems for me).

**Edit based on comment:**

If I understand your UI layout (the screenshot is a bit difficult to make out fully) and problem correctly...

You'd have to create a good old fashioned `IBAction` method, hook up each `UIButton` and call `setSelectedIndex:` on the `UITabBarController`.

Comment: Unfortunately, all of the seques eminate from the navigation controller.  If you look at the last scene, along the bottom you will see multi-colored UIButtons; when a button is tapped, I want to go to the first scene.  Any ideas on how to accomplish that?